# Jquery show one result for multiple returns?

Tags: jquery, each

I've got a simple script that when you select a school it advises if staff are available for reallocation.

Currently if it returns multiple results I get the message shown on screen multiple times. eg: if 3 staff are available I get

`Staff Member/s are available
 Staff Member/s are available
 Staff Member/s are available`

When all I want it just one line.

`Staff Member/s are available`

This is the code that loops through each available member of staff, it then calls `list` to filter and display the results.

For simplicity I stripped back `list` just to show what it does.

```
if (staff.length >=1) {
    $.each($.unique(staff.split(',')), function(key, val) { 
        list(val);
    });
}

function list(ID) {

        if($.inArray(ID, myArray) != -1) {
            var available = true;
        } else {
            var all = true;
        }

    if (available) $("#status").prepend('<li>Staff Member/s are available</li>');
}
```

Within in list how can I stop the message being shown if it's already displayed ?

I've tried to add a counter to this, and only display if `staffCount === 1` but that didn't seem to work.

Anyone any ideas ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is because you're calling `append()` in each iteration. Instead you can change the logic to only perform the check on the result of all items in the array. Try this:

```js
if (staff.length) {
  var available = false;
  $.each($.unique(staff.split(',')), function(key, val) {
    if ($.inArray(val, myArray) != -1) {
      available = true;
      return false;
    }
  });

  if (available) 
    $("#status").prepend('<li>Staff Member/s are available</li>');
}
```

Comment: once we have the result `available = true`, we should let it `return false;` to stop the loop right away (we don't need to loop more). That's one interesting thing about the `.each` method. BTW you have a typo about the variable `available` right at the line declaring it. Also looks like you have 1 redundant `)` at the end of the `if` which is at this line `($.inArray(val, myArray) != -1))`

Comment: @KingKing all very valid points, thanks. I updated the answer

Comment: you're welcome. I've just come back to the world of HTML and Javascript (about 2 years playing with other things). There is one more noticeable thing here, from the OP's code, I guess `staff` is some ***string***, so using `split` on it will return an array of string. However the `$.unique` is usable only on array of DOM elements (as specified here http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.unique/). Despite of the name (fairly confused), looks like that's one wrong thing of the OP.

Comment: Thanks that has helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Can't say is the best, but here's another way to do it: remove it every time you add it.

```
...
if (available) $("#status").prepend(function() {
  $("#avail").remove();
  return '<li id="avail">Staff Member/s are available</li>
});
```

Or create an element and replace all of the HTML: (@diavolic)

```
...
if (available) $("#status").prepend('<li id="avail" />').find("#avail").html('Staff Member/s are available')
```

Answer (score 0):

try to replace

```
    if (available) $("#status").prepend('<li>Staff Member/s are available</li>');
```

to

```
    if (available) $("#status").html('<li>Staff Member/s are available</li>');
```